# Find equilibrium points when given polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system given in polar coordinates

$\dot{r}=-r^3+r+r\sin{(2\theta)}/2$ and $\dot{\theta} = 1+\cos^2{\theta}$.

Find all equilibria and show that there are no invariant circles centered at the origin.

I know that when a system is given in cartesian coordinates then we convert to polar coordinates. And to find equilibria, we just look at values of $x$ and $y$ such that $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ are $0$. But here, we are given only polar coordinates. Can we convert it back to cartesian coordinates and then find equilibrium points? Otherwise, using polar coordinates, I can think of only origin as the equilibrium point since $r=0$ will yield $\dot{r}=0$. And no other point will yield $\dot{\theta}=0$. So would origin be the only equilibrium point? And how do we show there are no invariant circles centered at the origin?

Comment: Notice that when $r=0$, the value of $\theta$ is irrelevant since all values map to the origin. So $r=0$ is indeed an equilibrium point of the system.

Comment: Thanks Ninad. That's what I thought. Just wanted to know if we could go back to cartesian coordinates to find other possible equilibrium points.

Answer (score 2):

We have by chain rule that

$$\begin{cases}\dot{x} = \dot{r}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta\dot{\theta} = r\left(\cos\theta-r^2\cos\theta-\sin\theta\right)\\ \dot{y} = \dot{r}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta\dot{\theta} = r(\sin\theta-r^2\sin\theta+2\cos\theta)\end{cases}$$

which easily verifies the trivial solution we found earlier, but thanks to things canceling out also gives us the system

$$\begin{cases}r^2 = 1 - \tan\theta \\ r^2 = 1+2\cot\theta\end{cases}$$

which has no solutions because

$$-\tan\theta = 2\cot\theta \implies \tan^2\theta =-2$$

Therefore the origin is the only equilibrium point. An invariant circle means that there exists a sensible solution to $\dot{r} = 0$ but notice that solving that gets us

$$r^2 = 1 + \sin\theta\cos\theta$$

where $r$ is no longer constant, a contradiction.